# Only Interpolating within a polygon feature in ArcMap 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, spatial-analyst, kriging

I have sample points within a single polygon feature class that I would like to interpolate, likely using kriging.  The problem is the sample points and polygon boundaries are many miles apart and therefore the kriging interpolates across these many miles.  Is there anyway I could force the kriging to only interpolate within the polygons and not across what looks to be extents of the polygons.  Another way of saying this is let's assume I have sample data points in Missouri and Ohio and I want to compare across these two states so any chance I could merge the 2 states in single feature class and interpolate them together?  It just creates a big rectangle to the extents when I try kriging this data.

Comment: I am having problems with this issue. I have created a polygon shapefile that basically defines the geoprgaphic boundary of a set of points containing air concentration data, which i would like to interpolate (again using a Kriging model). I have set the mask to this polygon, but my output continues to be a large rectangle defined by the most northern, easter, southern and western points where the data was measured. There are large swathes of interpolated data (in the SW and NW corners of this rectangle especially) that are more or less non-sensical outputs as there are no points close to inte

Comment: Hi David. Welcome to GIS stackexchange. You will not get help in this way, best thing is delete this and post it as a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to limit kriging to only interpolate within the polygons, you could adjust your Environment Settings. You can do this by selecting Geoprocessing - Environment Settings.
Within there you should select Raster Analysis. This is where you can set the Mask for your workspace. Raster Analysis performed in your workspace will only be performed within the boundary of your set Mask. So, in your case, you would want to select that polygon layer as your Mask.

Comment: Thanks hurlski, that did the trick.  I do have what sort of strange thing going on where it's leaving out some of the far edges of the polygon I'm using in the mask.  Like maybe they don't match the 4 outer extents of the polygen area or something.  Any ideas on what my be going on there if I'm explaining that well enought?

Comment: I think you should look into your Environment settings, specifically the Processing Extent. I don't know exactly what is going on with your dataset, but it sounds like it could be a misalignment issue. You can correct this by adding a Snap Raster under the Processing Extent section of Environment Settings. You might also want to take a look at the Cell Size settings in the Raster Analysis section. Good Luck