# Creating polygons using mask layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, extents, masking, voronoi-thiessen

[I looked at this question, but it only answers part of my problem.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83298/only-interpolating-within-a-polygon-feature-in-arcmap-10-1/83304#83304)
I want to create Thiessen polygons based off of the green points within the blue polygon boundary ONLY.  I've set the Processing extent to the exchange boundary, and have set the raster analysis mask to the same exchange boundary.

When I run the Thiessen polygons tool, it will still use the largest extent of the polygon, not the actual borders of the polygon.  You can see that polygons are created for points outside of the blue border.  Is there a step I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: Try selecting the points inside your boundary then run the Thiessen tool?

Comment: I think that's what I'll end up doing.  I can create thiessen polygons based off of a selection of the points within the boundary, and then just clip the polygons to the boundary afterwards.  I was just hoping there was a way to avoid that extra step.